# POM.xml showing errors

Tags: java, maven-2

After converting dynamic web project to Maven project in eclipse, POM.xml is throwing errors
show below.

> No plugin found for prefix 'war' in the current project and in the plugin groups [] available from the repositories [local (/home/guruputra/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: please this before asking question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, posting your pom.xml would help :)

Comment: Right_click on project --> maven --> updateProject (select All). Try this

Comment: Thanks for replay.                                                                                                      i have already tried that, but no use. still it's giving same error

Comment: it worked with: Right_click on project --> maven --> updateProject (select All). Thanks Roshan